# Water leaking through vanity, through gap between faucet base and sink

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, vanity

I have a bathroom faucet with a leaking issue. Whenever any water ends up on the top of the vanity or around the faucet base, it seems to leak through and drip down the bottom of the vanity. In order words, it doesn't seem like it's properly sealed. Is there supposed to a watertight seal using silicone or plumber's putty to prevent this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is supposed to be a watertight seal. All the valves and spigots are supposed to either have a gasket of some sort or sealed with plumber's putty at the time of installation. They can deteriorate with age. The drain seat should also be sealed. You have two choices: remove the fixture and put on some plumber's putty and reinstall or get some silicone caulk and place a bead of it around the fixture after cleaning the area and letting it dry completely.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would fix it myself but this is occurring in an apartment i am renting. I mentioned it to two of my landlord's people twice, and they seemed confused at the concept of a "watertight seal" or said nothing could be done.